# Run typescript files/ with decorator at same time

Tags: typescript, decorator

I've the following scenario:

- Five `class`;
- Each one of five `class` has the same decorator `@test`;
- Decorator `@test` get all `functions` of a `class` and store in static variable `tests`;

I want to run all methods at the same time that is stored in static variable `tests`. So, how can I do that?

obs: I'm studying typescript, so, I'm a new one with the language. And I'm trying to create for study purposes a framework that run tests similar to MSTest, nUnit, xUnit (c#).

class exemple:

```
@test()
class TestDataUnitsTest {

    public startup() {

    }

    public testOne(){

    }

    public testTwo(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const tests: { [name: string]: Function } = {};

function Test() {
     return function (target: Function) {
          const proto = target.prototype;
          const functions = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)
               .filter(prop => prop !== 'constructor')
               .map(prop => proto[prop])
               .filter(prop => typeof prop === 'function');

          functions.forEach((fn: Function) => tests[`${target.name}.${fn.name}`] = fn)
     };
}
```

See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?strictFunctionTypes=false&experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0IC4YG8YG0wEMC28q0ATgJZgDmAuqgGICuYwUp4MAvjALzrsDcAKAEAzRs1ZgYAFURQAFAEp0AmKtXF4UesUmimLNnKg5iFTXTEGwStCrX3VoSLAAOxEFBDc4Js1AB0bh4eAJ4u8IIODk7QMHri4BDeAPIARgBW8Mz%20fskA7mAACu7hxFAhAHL4iHJBngp2UU3%20wqQANgjEtSXcAHwwQS4wAIRcPADkMVDE9MwgxOMNTcv%20eDgu3SBDXP11IJiDVEvLUS3tnZvb-eXhIMIDPWMT8VaLgo1NLxIQLfMAojhgAALORyYRgCz6CRKHZwWQQTAAAwAJGhjKZNP5cAR2P5UeCsdV2IiqN5wcc1PwBOwhAABGTQRQCYBtHAQJIMqAAYVZ7IAjMpoolprNPF0XPRUm1SMAHlsAMzeeU2GAxEBteD%20NogChycacnlsiB8-xTGZzBZKGkfOHQPmKdCqxLqzXa3X62SG-n%20BB2xYcG2%20qAAJgdGDVGq1Or1Bt5xp9smD-ppDiD8rDTsgLqj7tjRpNaeTQgcgwFPD5kXsg2D3mD7wcfhgfk69oUqDA9DwqXgxEdGi0OhgABY%20AGHBBNDAJ1AW3IAG44Nrtzvd4gqmnW%20myJkso3ST1xmu2VOyVuOiOu6Me6BeiDBhN%20q2BxMZi85mMHo33oNJp8n6Dpiqb5uh%20N6Hg%20UDykW1ppJk2QANbwCEEBGPCCi-MQALAnI8F9LaUAIvBVCKAofBAA)